# Plot real part of complex-valued function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, complex-numbers, real-number

I am trying to plot the following function...

```
f(k) = Re[k - 0.5*(sqrt(1 - 4*k) + 1)]
```

for `k = [-2, 2]`, but the best I can do is...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
k = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
f = np.real(k - 0.5*(np.sqrt(1 - 4*k) + 1))
plt.plot(k, f)
plt.axis([-2,2,-10,10])
```

which plots fine for `k = [-2, 1/4)` but nothing for complex results. Can I do this some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to tell to `np.sqrt` that you are using complex number an easy way is to add `0j`at the end of the parameter. After you call the real part of your result. You can also use [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html) `numpy.lib.scimath.sqrt`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
k = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
f = np.array(k - 0.5*(np.sqrt(1 - 4*k+0j) + 1))
plt.plot(k, f.real)
plt.axis([-2,2,-10,10])
plt.show()
```

I'm getting this plot
[image]

With your code I was getting
[image]